# Rank of endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f\colon V \to V$ be an Endomorphism of a finite-dimensional K-Vector space V.

Let $r_k$ be $rank(f^k)$, now I want to show that
$$1.) r_k ≥ r_{k+1}$$
$$2.) r_k - r_{k+1} ≥ r_{k+1}-r_{k+2} $$
3.) If 1.) and 2.) are true and if there is a $k≥ 0$ so that $r_k = r_{k+1}$, then $r_k =r_{k+l}$ for every $l≥0$

Now I already showed 1.) and with 1.) Ajd 2.) I can show 3.) by induction. The problem is 2.). I do not know how to proof this.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V_k$ be the image of $f^k$. This gives a decreasing chain of subspaces
$$ V \overset{f}{\to} V_1 \overset{f}{\to} V_2 \overset{f}{\to} \cdots \overset{f}{\to} V_k \overset{f}{\to} V_{k+1} \overset{f}{\to} V_{k+2} \overset{f}{\to} \cdots $$

By definition, $r_k = \dim V_k$, and the restriction $f \colon V_k \to V_{k+1}$ is surjective. So by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, the difference $r_k - r_{k+1}$ is the dimension of the kernel of $f$ (restricted to $V_k$). And so also $r_{k+1}-r_{k+2}$ is the dimension of the kernel of $f$, restricted to $V_{k+1}$.

But since $V_{k+1} \subseteq V_k$, the kernel of $f$ on $V_{k+1}$ is a subset of the kernel of $f$ on $V_k$. This gives the inequality.